# proper syntax for subprocess.call()

Tags: python, hadoop, python-2.6

I have the following script:

```
import glob
import subprocess
import os

filePath = "/tmp/ming"
keyword = "GC10^Dummy-Segment"

#if keyword in filePath:
new=glob.glob('/tmp/ming/*Dummy-Segment*')
print(new)
for x in new:
    subprocess.call(['hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal {0} /user/app'.format(x)], shell=True)
```

print(new) yields:

```
['/tmp/mike/GC10^Dummy-Segment_2018', '/tmp/mike/GC10^Dummy-Segment_2019']
```

Seeing the following errors:

```
copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException
copyFromLocal: unexpected URISyntaxException
```

In an earlier attempt, I had to replace the ^ with %5E but I'm really not sure how to substitute the ^ now.

I think for each x in new, I have to add in %5E where the ^ is, then do the copyFromLocal. But how do I do that?

Also, I'm running Python 2.6.6

Comment: The `x` python variable is not being transferred to the `$x` variable in the command.

Comment: Also, you're _sure_ the path is `/user`, and not `/usr`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Yes, path is /user. I can do hdfs dfs -ls /user/app

Comment: Perhaps it's because the command doesn't have a space between `$x` and `/user/app`, so it's effectively `$x/user/app`, and `$x` is (presumably) an undefined variable.

Comment: @JohnGordon I added a space after the $x: ```subprocess.call(['hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal $x ' + '/user/edwaeadt'], shell=True)``` Still seeing the same error. Also, if I can't use $x, what should I use?

Comment: You'll have to use Python string formatting to insert the contents of `x`.  Try this: `'hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal {} /user/edwaeadt'.format(x)`.  That will replace the placeholder token `{}` in the string with the value of `x`.

Comment: And `/user/app` is only 'legit' in hadoop's distributed file system, not in local one, and since it can't resolve `$x` it assumes `/user/app` is the first argument, which is the source path in local fs and doesn't exist.

Comment: @JohnGordon, I'm seeing this error: ```ValueError: zero length field name in format``` Any ideas?

Comment: Some python versions require a number inside the `{}` brackets.  Use `{0}` instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon, that worked! Thanks. Although I have a different error now related to the ^ in the file name.

Comment: Doies your HDFS command work from HDFS command line? Can you list the files you mention? Does prepending `hdfs://` to the paths help?

Comment: @9000 adding ```hdfs://``` doesn't help. Still facing the same error. I know the error is a result of the ^. I just don't know how, for each instance of x, substitute the ^ with %5E.

Comment: `x.replace` would help with that